# What is a Proper Signature for a Vector Space?

Tags: model-theory

The definition of a signature I'm working with is a quadruple $\sigma = (C,F,R,\sigma')$ with $C$ serving as a set of constant symbols, $F$ serving as a set of function symbols, and $R$ serving as a set of relation symbols.  Finally we have the arity function $\sigma':F \cup R \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

**Question:** What is an appropriate signature to describe a vector space?

Since a vector space can be viewed as an abelian group $V$ together with a field $\mathcal{K}$, is the following appropriate?

1. $C = \{0_V, 0_K, 1_K\}$
2. $F = \{+_V, +_K, \cdot_K\}$
3. $R = \emptyset$
4. Define $\sigma'$ to be as follows: $\sigma'(+_V) = \sigma'(+_K) = \sigma'(\cdot_K) = 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your signature (I think the more common term is "language") is not appropriate for vector spaces, because you want to be able to multiply scalars with vectors, but scalars need not be elements of the vector space. The signature frequently used for vector spaces is:
1. $C=\{0\}$
2. $F=\{+\}\cup K$ (i.e. one unitary function symbol for each element of the scalar field)
3. $R=\emptyset$
4. $\sigma^{\prime}(+)=2, \sigma^{\prime}(x)=1$ for $x\in K$

For $x\in K, \bar v\in V$, $x(\bar v)$ will be interpreted as $x\cdot\bar v$.

Comment: Wow -- viewing each element of $K$ as a function symbol to solve the problem you mentioned blew my mind.  Very interesting construction.

Comment: Blew my mind too, the first time I saw it.

Comment: Does one need a way to describe the inverse elements of $V$ and $K$?  That is, should we add the symbol $-$ to $F$?  (I'm not sure how we would go about describing the inverse multiplicative elements of $F$).

Comment: What do you mean by "inverse elements of $V$ and $K$"? $V$ only has additive inverses, which can either be denoted by the term $(-1)(\bar v)$ (viewing $-1$ as an element of $K$) or by the formula $\bar v+x=0$. The multiplicative inverses in $K$ don't need description, because they are not in the domain of discourse.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to write $F=\{+\}\cup K$.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Editing...

Comment: Point taken on us already being able to specify additive inverses in $V$, but it seems throughout the course of linear algebra often useful for us to be able to specify scalar inverses as well.  But what you're saying, if I understand it right, is that we're fitting this signature to $V$ (i.e., the underlying set of vectors) and as such there aren't scalar inverses to specify in the first place?

Comment: You are right that there are no scalars in the underlying set, but you are also right that scalar inverses can be useful. However, there is no need to somehow "define" them, since every scalar is already represented by a function symbol.